# Positive Definite Multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let ($X$,$A$,$\mu$) be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $g$ $\in$ $L^{\infty}(\mu)$. Define $M_g$: $L^2(\mu)$ $\longrightarrow$ $L^2(\mu)$ by setting $M_g(f)$ = $fg$. Show that if $M_g$ a positive definite operator then $g$ $\geq$ $0$ a.e. on $X$.
I have already shown that $M_g$ is self-adjoint if $g(x)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ for a.e $x$ $\in$ $X$. I have got upto $\int_X g|f|^2d\mu $ $\geq$ $0$ for each $f$ $\in$ $L^2(\mu)$. How do I conclude that $g$ $\geq$ $0$ a.e from here? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $g < 0$ on some set of non-zero measure $A$. Since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, we can assume $\mu(A)$ to be finite. We have for the indicator function that $\chi_A \in L^2(\mu)$ and we also have 
$$
\int_X g \chi_A d\mu < 0,
$$
which is a contradiction. So $g$ is positive almost everywhere.